# What to do about two answers by the same user to the same question

Tags: discussion, answers, users

I know it's possible to have two answers on the same question on Stack Overflow, but what if those two answers are from the same user and there is no need to post both?

Should I report answers of this kind or just ask the user to edit into one answer?

...Or is it just fine to post two such answers?

An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801250/forwarding-webrtc-video-for-peer-to-peer-broadcasting).

Answer (score 8):

A person can put as many answers to a question as he/she wants.

This is allowed as long as the answers are fundamentally different. If the user is just spreading their single answer across multiple posts, that is a way of "cheating the system" to get more reputation, and should be flagged.